Problem Using Selenium to Click on a Cookie Overlay
I am trying to access a website using Selenium Python and, in order to do so, I want to reject cookies (or accept, whichever would be fine at this point). I see the button that I want to click in the html but even when I ask the driver to wait, it just doesn't see it. Could you please help ?
Here is my script, I also tried looking for an iframe but it doesn't seem like that's the issue but perhaps I'm wrong. Also sorry for the long url haha
driver.get("https://parisportif.pmu.fr/home/wrapper/events?lang=fr&activeSportId=1&leagues=%5B123,261,486,273,292,38,705,541,619,304,1383,1149,349,1381,315,362,916,96,607,514,429,1987,684,317,131,197,1792,795,65,553,685,297,114,70,570,224,382,922,777,240,852,412,428,249,589,862,1821,1253,1251,779,551,530,925,415,873,594,1266,1513,420,216,434,669,543,1150,911,600,156,341,108,130,41,896,1146,208,935,260%5D&boost=%5B123,273,1146%5D")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "WelcomeStep__DiscardButton-sc-18c5grd-0.bOlaxk.ax-discardButton"))).click()



That control is in an iframe, so you need to switch to the iframe first:
driver.switch_to.frame("sportsbook_iframe")

Then you can click to accept cookies with this CSS Selector:
"#axeptio_btn_acceptAll"

Could have sworn I ran something like that already but it worked ! Thanks a lot !
